# Is your eye has sand in it?

Tags: grammar

He barely can't open one of his eye.

"Sand" he told me.

> "Is your eye has sand in it?"
>
> "Sand got in your eye?"

Do they sound natural to a native speaker?

When we have no idea the quantity of the sand. We normally use singular or plurar?

Comment: No they don't. It would be better if you explain why you wrote them this way.

Comment: Questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on something in particular that you are unsure about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say one of these:

> **Does** your eye **have** sand in it?
>
> **Has** sand got in your eye?

Or:

> Did you get sand in your eye?

Conversationally, it doesn’t need to be a full sentence:

> Sand in your eye?

Because *sand* is an uncountable noun, we use the singular form, no matter how much sand may or may not be in the eye.

---

Also, as a footnote, you should say:

> He can barely open one of his eyes.

Or:

> He can’t open one of his eyes.

but not:

> <strike>He can’t barely open</strike>...